# How to make compilation fail if both or none preprocessor macro is defined

Tags: c++, macros, preprocessor-directive

Friend asked me for help in C++. I do not use C++ only C#(WP,WPF,WinForms) and Java(Android).

The part of the task he has is when the macro STAR is defined he should draw a christmass tree with * (stars) when the macro EQ is defined he suppose to draw it with = (assign operator). If both or none is defined compilation has failed. Drawing christmass tree is easy task in any language but I have problems with those preprocessor macros.

```
#define STAR *
#define EQ =

#if !(defined(STAR) ^ defined(EQ)) 
   FAIL TO COMPILE?
#endif
```

How to check then in code which macro is defined and assign its' value to the `char character;`?

Answer (score 18):

You want the [#error](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x5hedts0.aspx) pre-processor directive

Answer (score 9):

There is a preprocessor directive for that:

```
#error "One and only one of STAR or EQ should be defined"
```

Comment: It does not depend on the compiler - `#error` is standard.

Comment: @WojtekSurowka, thanks, I wasn't sure about it. I was coincidentally reading [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor#Compiler-specific_preprocessor_features) earlier today saying `#warning` is not standard and by analogy I assumed `#error` is not either.

Answer (score 2):

I did this task for him. The preprocessor instructions look like:

```
 #define STAR "*"
// #define EQ "="
 #if !(defined(STAR) ^ defined(EQ))
      #error "STAR XOR EQ have to be defined"
 #elif (defined(STAR))
        #define CHARACTER STAR
 #elif (defined(EQ))
        #define CHARACTER EQ
 #endif
```